# OpenCV Java Qualifier Must be an Expression

Tags: java, opencv

I am getting the following error on the `net` object in this code `qualifier must be an expression`

```
Mat blob = Dnn.blobFromImage(inputFrame, IN_SCALE_FACTOR, new Size(IN_WIDTH, IN_HEIGHT), new Scalar(MEAN_VAL, MEAN_VAL, MEAN_VAL), true, false);
net.setInput(blob);

List<List<Double>> blobList = new ArrayList<>();

Mat detections = net.forward();
```

For more information the code is taken from this post: [OpenCV DNN Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59606236/opencv-dnn-java)

The imports were not provided with the code so I am trying to figure out what is missing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: "Qualifier must be an expression" - Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35114242/error-qualifier-must-be-an-expression-android-studio)

Comment: [mre] requires proper error message/traceback/stack trace. you haven't said what exact code causes this error